# Android - How to make sure sound output is not picked up by microphone

Tags: android, recording

So I am trying to build a recorder app in Android.
I want to record sound that is spoken to the device while ignoring any sound output that goes out of the phone.

Here is a use case.

The phone plays a song.
The mic turns on, waiting for user's input. The music is still playing.
The user says "Hello world"
The mic picks up "Hello world" but it doesn't catch the song playing in the background.

Is there a way to do so? Whenever I try to record, it record both user's voice and the sound that goes out of the inbuilt speaker. I wonder if this is technically possible.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AudioRecord while also playing audio - accessing output playback data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025219/audiorecord-while-also-playing-audio-accessing-output-playback-data)

Comment: Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560814/acousticechocanceler-on-samsung-devices-not-working) might help with implementation details.